Function type as Promise resolve type
I found this particular interesting typescript code not only runs but also compiles with no error at all.
function Me() : Promise<number>
{
    return new Promise(
        (resolve: Function, reject)=>
        {
            resolve("me");
        }
    )
}

Me().then(v=>{console.log(v);}); //print "me"

resolve should be a (value: number | PromiseLike<number>) => void type, but it seems that it gets around the typing system. How is it possible or am I not setting a stricter compilation setting?

Since you added Function type annotation which defines the parameter's type as any, so you basically turned off the type checking with this any. If you remove the annotation all will be working fine.
